# Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server - Does Not Connect

Tags: drivers, microsoft, odbc

```
sqlcmd  -S 192.168.1.86\\SQLEXPRESS,1443 -U c -P e
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

The SQLServer is open to remote logins, but I cannot access the database...

Ubuntu 20.04
Microsoft ODBC driver for 20.04/php 7.4

I installed mssql-server and I cannot connect to that,

```
qlcmd  -S localhost -U andrew -P Let1Me2In
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'andrew'..
```

Comment: Are you able to connect remotely via SSMS or another tool  but not PHP?

Comment: Yes as this is my EPOS database, my back office is a laptop connected over the network, this is a new install on a new machine 20.04, the old machine worked 16.04.